# Update the user

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to update the user using this Form:

```
        {!! Form::model($user ,['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=>['AdminController@update',$user->id], 'files'=>true]) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('first_name','First Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('first_name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('last_name','Last Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('last_name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('username','Username (Student ID):') !!}
            {!! Form::number('username',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('email','Email:') !!}
            {!! Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('address','Address:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('address','null',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('phone_number','Phone Number:') !!}
            {!! Form::number('phone_number','null',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
         </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('password','Password:') !!}
            {!! Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Update User', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary col-sm-6']) !!}
        </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and this is my Route:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
  Route::post('/users/{id}','AdminController@update');
)};
```

when I press update button I receive this error:

[image: error message that I received]

Please help me, I am Using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Try changing Form method to POST

Comment: Not working with POST method

Comment: Try - `'action'=> '/users/' . $user->id` and `method = post`

Comment: I ever used action in Form helper. Maybe that is the issue. Try changing "action" to "url' => 'admin/users'.$user->id

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'PUT'))  }}

 // form fiedls come here    

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

in route file add following route:

```
Route::resource('users', "UserController");
```

and in user controller add following code:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id){

    // Add form validation here


    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->save();

    Session::Flash('success', 'The User have been updated successfully!');
    return redirect()->route('users.index');

}
```

don't user AdminController to manage users.

Comment: can you post your all routes here?

Comment: Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/users', 'AdminController@create')->name('create.user');
    Route::get('/admin/users','AdminController@showAllUsers')->name('all-users');
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::post('/users', 'AdminController@store');
    Route::get('/users/edit/{id}', 'AdminController@edit')->name('edit-user');
    Route::PUT('/users/{id}','AdminController@update')->name('update-user');
});

Comment: no, my mean run "php artisan route:list" in your terminal and share the output

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain what your code achieves in detail so that your answer will be more relevant for future users :)

Comment: I add my route list in my post. you can see it now

Answer (score 0):

Please use PATCH in routes for example :

Route::patch('/users/{id}','AdminController@update');

Answer (score 0):

your method is post , but you send patch request

you should change to this

```
'method'=>'post'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to fix every thing

form blade

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('update-user', $user->id), 'method' => 'PUT'))  }}
```

route

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::PUT('/users/{id}','AdminController@update')->name('update-user');
 )};
```

Comment: I used that, but I received new error: undefined variable user

Comment: if this is a edit page , you should pass user for update, in this code i call user object by $user , you should pass user object to this view